# If it possible to get the abstract controller from a nested state in $stateProvider

Tags: angularjs

I'm using `$stateProvider` with `AngularJS` and I'm wondering if there's any way to get the abstract, or parent, controller from a child state. Before you throw `$parent` out there, it doesn't seem to work as I thought it would.

Example:

```
$stateProvider.state('page',
{
    url: '/page',
    abstract: true,
    cache: false,
    templateUrl: 'navigation.html',
    controller: 'navigationController'       
});

$stateProvider.state('page.login',
{
    url: '/login',
    templateUrl: '...',
    views: 
    {
        'login':
        {
            templateUrl: 'login.html',
            controller: 'loginController'
        }
   }     
});
```

So, the question is, how would I modify a value in `navigationController` from `loginController`.

EX:

```
var navigationController = function($scope) {
    $scope.showNavigation = true;
}

var loginController = function($scope) {
    $scope.onClicked = function() {
        // navigationController::$scope.showNavigation = false
    }
}
```

I've tried using `$scope.$parent.showNavigation` but that doesn't modify the value. Printing `$scope.$parent` yields an unreadable nested object of the current scope.